# AlpineJS expression error "option is not defined" in x-for loop

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm using AlpineJS to generate a filterable dropdown menu using `x-for` on a `<template>`. The code is actually working as intended but the console shows an error when the page is first loaded:

```
Expression: "filter_options.includes(option.text)"
```

The AlpineJS data is generated from a function, the two components used to generate the dropdown options are `options`, a list of objects with values such as name, id, selected, etc. and `filter_options` which is a list of strings that match the search value.

The for loop is generated from the `options` list but then has an `x-if` template within to check if the option is contained within the `filter_options` list - those filtered options are based on the value in the search input (not shown).

```js
export function dropdown() {
  return {
      search: "", // e.g. 'New'
      options: [
      {
        name: "New York",
        id: "123",
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        ...
      }],
      filter_options: ["New York", "New Jersey"],
      ...
  }
}
```

The offending section of HTML is below, it seems that Alpine is trying to process `option.text` before `option` is defined but I don't know why that would be the case as it's wrapped into a `<template>` tag with the `x-for` loop.

```html
<template x-if="filter_options.length>0" x-for="(option,index) in options" :key="option">
  <div>
    <template x-if="filter_options.includes(option.text)">
      <div :class="option.selected ? 'font-semibold' : 'font-normal'" x-model="option" x-text="option.text"></div>
```

I have tried delaying `option.text` being called by using an if-statement, i.e. `option ? option.selected : false` but it still produces the same error. I have also tried to re-write the HTML so that `x-for="(option,index) in options"` becomes `x-for="(option,index) in filter_options"` but the same issue persists.

Is there a way that I can guarantee that `option` has loaded before accessing `option.text`?

Comment: Is `filter_options` a value that supports `includes` upon page load?

Comment: Yes, it's' an empty list upon page load so should just return `false`